# Set the cell as ReadOnly in Datagrid in code-behind - Cell has different value

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

In Wpf DataGrid, I would like to make few cells readonly based on some other factors. Finally I get a Dictionary which has 1,2 which is Row 1 column 2 should be read only. How to achieve this in code.

EDIT: The below is the datagrid. I would like to make second row, first column cell value 2,00 to be readonly in code-behind. I cant bind any value in the template, because I am not uisng cell value for cell readable.

I prefer better option would be while loading the row, uisng rowIndex and col index point the cell, then apply style as "IsEnabled=FAlse".Is it possible?????????

[image]

grd_elements.Rows not available for me. 
Only grd_elements.Items(0) always refer to the class, am binding the rows dynamically and grd_elements.Items(0).cells(1).visibility=Visibility.Collapsed throw an error say the property of the class not found.

```
Private Sub Grd_elements_LoadingRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridRowEventArgs) Handles grd_elements.LoadingRow
        Dim oDatagridRow As cls_PmZeile = CType(e.Row.Item, cls_PmZeile)
        For Each column As DataGridColumn In grd_elements.Columns
            If column.DisplayIndex = 0 Then Continue For 

  grd_elements.Columns(column.DisplayIndex).GetCellContent(e.Row).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
        Next
```

error cant find the object instance in the above code:(

Target is, to loop through the datagridRow while loading each row in loading row event, and set the cell Visibility as Collapsed.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution for the problem.##vb.net### Dim cellContent = grd_elements.Columns(2).GetCellContent(grd_elements.Items(3)) Dim cell As DataGridCell = CType(cellContent?.Parent, DataGridCell) cell.Style = CType(grdTotal.FindResource("dataGridCellLvlHide"), Style)´´´´ ##XAML####´´<Style x:Key="dataGridCellLvlHide" TargetType="DataGridCell"> <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" /> <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" /> </Style>´´´´